# Integer.MAX_VALUE in java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have read about MAX_VALUE and found that a constant can hold a maximum value of 2^31-1. Where is the need to use a MAX_VALUE for any program?

I am also confused on this piece of stack code, where if the stack is empty it return Integer.Max_VALUE.

```
if(s2.isEmpty())
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Why should we return a max number when the stack is empty ?

Comment: you might need it to check if an integer addition might get to create an overflow. It´s also a nice initializer if you want to find the max and min values in an array of int´s

Comment: Can't you check how this return value is used in the code? Why do yo need to guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example usage of `MAX_VALUE`:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 182938, 1293);
Integer min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (Integer i : l) { 
     min = Math.min(min, i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I have hardly ever used this, but for one thing it is quite practical:

If you are searching for a minimum, you can inititally start with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as it is guaranteed that the next value will be smaller.

The second use case scenario is to check if this variable can be used for any further calculations, by checking `(var <= Integer.MAX_VALUE - valueToAdd && valueToAdd >= 0)` beforehand.

Returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is nice if you certainly know that a number cannot possible be that high. I often use `-1` as return value if an int cannot be negative, but if it can you need to think of something else, which would be using `MAX_VALUE` then.

Comment: i´d add to this that `valueToAdd` should definitely be `>= 0`, otherwise this condition could be true and could still create an overflow.